# Analysis of dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activex

Is it possible to examine a dll, not installed in the registry, to see if it an ActiveX, the public methods, if it supports COM, etc.  Is there some other tool with which to analyze a dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very generic question, but you can analyze a dll's exported methods and ASM code using some decompiler/debugger like OllyDbg. Of course you need to have a good understanding of ASM and Windows inner workings.

http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html

if you have Visual Studio and just want to know if the dll contains a COM component, you can open the visual studio command prompt, and use:

```
dumpbin /exports filename.dll
```

to show the dll's exported functions. If the dll exports DllGetClassObject, DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer, it contains a COM component.

Example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>dumpbin /exports c:\windows\system32\quartz.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file c:\windows\system32\quartz.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for QUARTZ.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5215E909 time date stamp Thu Aug 22 12:33:45 2013
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           8 number of functions
           8 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0003B34C AMGetErrorTextA
          2    1 0003B41C AMGetErrorTextW
          3    2 0003B2C8 AmpFactorToDB
          4    3 0003B314 DBToAmpFactor
          5    4 00002848 DllCanUnloadNow
          6    5 000032E0 DllGetClassObject
          7    6 0003AFA0 DllRegisterServer
          8    7 0003B2A0 DllUnregisterServer

  Summary

       36000 .data
        4000 .idata
        F000 .pdata
        4000 .reloc
        B000 .rsrc
      157000 .text
        1000 RT_CODE
```

Comment: @gufino02 I just need to know if a given dll is an ActiveX dll and what are the methods.  Is there not something in VS2010 that can so analyze a "raw" dll?  Thank you for such a quick and substantive response, all all so contributors.

Comment: I edited my answer to add Visual Studio's dumpbin usage to detect presence of COM components